# Have a toolbar docked independently from the taskbar in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, quicklaunch

In Windows XP, I'd make my Quicklaunch toolbar dock to the right side of my screen while the original Taskbar (was that the name?  I'm already forgetting...) was at the bottom.

In Windows 7, I can't get this to happen.  I can make a new toolbar, add icons to it, etc, but I cannot drag it outside of the bounds of the existing Taskbar.

I have unlocked the taskbar, etc, I've tried everything I can think of to get this to work.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [this ability was removed in Windows 7](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/can-i-separate-the-task-bar-and-tool-bar-that-are/4e0175be-05d9-4411-ab1c-973d8c755781), you're going to need a third party application.

Here's some to try and see which suits you best:

[Standalonestack](http://www.chrisnsoft.com/standalonestack/)

[Rocketdock](http://rocketdock.com/)

[Objectdock](http://www.stardock.com/products/objectdock/)

Comment: I've use Rocketdock, and it is okay.  I much prefer the size and feel of a toolbar docked the entire height of the screen with small icons.